# Bar Chart on Dimension-1 and Stacked by Dimension-2

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

### Summary

I want to display a bar chart whose dimension is days and is stacked by a different category (i.e. x-axis = days and stack = category-1). I can do this "manually" in that I can write if-then's to zero or display the quantity, but I'm wondering if there's a systematic way to do this.

**JSFiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/wostoj/rum53tn2/

### Details

I have data with dates, quantities, and other classifiers. For the purpose of this question I can simplify it to this:

```
data = [
 {day: 1, cat: 'a', quantity: 25},
 {day: 1, cat: 'b', quantity: 15},
 {day: 1, cat: 'b', quantity: 10},
 {day: 2, cat: 'a', quantity: 90},
 {day: 2, cat: 'a', quantity: 45},
 {day: 2, cat: 'b', quantity: 15},
]
```

I can set up a bar chart, by `day`, that shows total units and I can manually add the stacks for 'a' and 'b' as follows.

```
var dayDim = xf.dimension(_ => _.day);
var bar = dc.barChart("#chart");
bar
  .dimension(dayDim)
  .group(dayDim.group().reduceSum(
    _ => _.cat === 'a' ? _.quantity : 0
   ))
  .stack(dayDim.group().reduceSum(
    _ => _.cat === 'b' ? _.quantity : 0
   ));
```

However, this is easy when my data has only 2 categories, but I'm wondering how I'd scale this to 10 or an unknown number of categories. I'd imagine the pseudo-code I'm trying to do is something like

```
dc.barChart("#chart")
  .dimension(xf.dimension(_ => _.day))
  .stackDim(xf.dimension(_ => _.cat))
  .stackGroup(xf.dimension(_ => _.cat).group().reduceSum(_ => _.quantity));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned this in my answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51141367/stacked-bar-chart-by-units-percentage), but why not expand on it a little bit here.

[In the dc.js FAQ](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#what-if-rows-contain-a-single-value-but-a-different-value-per-row) there is a standard pattern for custom reductions to reduce more than one value at once.

Say that you have a field named `type` which determines which type of value is in the row, and the value is in a field named `value` (in your case these are `cat` and `quantity`). Then

```
var group = dimension.group().reduce(
    function(p, v) { // add
        p[v.type] = (p[v.type] || 0) + v.value;
        return p;
    },
    function(p, v) { // remove
        p[v.type] -= v.value;
        return p;
    },
    function() { // initial
        return {};
    });
```

will reduce all the rows for each bin to an object where the keys are the types and the values are the sum of values with that type.

The way this works is that when crossfilter encounters a new key, it first uses the "initial" function to produce a new value. Here that value is an empty object.

Then for each row it encounters which falls into the bin labelled with that key, it calls the "add" function. `p` is the previous value of the bin, and `v` is the current row. Since we started with a blank object, we have to make sure we initialize each value; `(p[v.type] || 0)` will make sure that we start from `0` instead of `undefined`, because `undefined + 1` is `NaN` and we hate NaNs.

We don't have to be as careful in the "remove" function, because the only way a row will be removed from a bin is if it was once added to it, so there must be a number in `p[v.type]`.

Now that each bin contains an object with all the reduced values, the stack mixin has helpful extra parameters for `.group()` and `.stack()` which allow us to specify the name of the group/stack, and the accessor.

For example, if we want to pull items `a` and `b` from the objects for our stacks, we can use:

```
.group(group, 'a', kv => kv.value.a)
.stack(group, 'b', kv => kv.value.b)
```

It's [not as convenient as it could be](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/797),  but you can use these techniques to [add stacks to a chart programmatically](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/stacked-bar.html) (see source).

Comment: Gordon, this is great. Thanks so much for the answer and even more for the explanation and demo.