# dc.js Box plot reducer using two groups

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I'm trying to produce a box plot which will show the total number of networks single devices have connected to grouped by their vendor.

Data Format:

```
{
    "SSID": "eduroam",
    "identifier": "Client",
    "latitude": 52.4505,
    "longitude": -1.9361,
    "mac": "dc:d9:16:##:##:##",
    "packet": "PR-REQ",
    "timestamp": "2018-07-10 12:25:26",
    "vendor": "Huawei Technologies Co.Ltd"
}
```

Fiddle with data
https://jsfiddle.net/v4a8g2bo/

I have managed to get a sum of the networks a single device has connected to using the following code. Data filtered before to only contain unique networks to a mac address, therefore using a counter works to count networks.

```
var mac = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d["mac"]; });
var SSIDstoSingleMAC = mac.group().reduceSum(function (d) { return 
+d.counter});
```

My problem lies when trying to then pass this grouped sum into a further group that will output an array for use in the box plot chart

```
var vendor = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d["vendor"]; });

//Used to count number of networks per device
var mac = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d["mac"]; });
var SSIDstoSingleMAC = mac.group().reduceSum(function (d) { return 
+d.counter});

//This is where things fall down
var boxplotGroup = SSIDstoSingleMAC.group().reduce(
    function (p, v) {
        let dv = v.counter;
        if (dv != null) p.push(dv);
        return p;
    },
    function (p, v) {
        let dv = v.counter;
        if (dv != null) p.splice(p.indexOf(dv), 1);
        return p;
    },
    function () {
        return [];
    }
);

var boxPlot = dc.boxPlot("#boxPlot");
boxPlot
    .width(1200)
    .height(600)
    .dimension(vendor)
    .group(boxplotGroup)
    .tickFormat(d3.format('.1f'))
    .elasticY(true)
    .elasticX(true)
;
```

This is the goal:
Ex. Apple [7,5,10,2] = four apple devices.. device one has connected to 7 networks... ect.. 
[image: The Goal]

### ATTEMPT AT HIDDEN GROUP

Gordon mentioned in the comments that two groups can't be passed recursively in crossfilter. I'm now trying to produce a hidden group that can accumulate the networks per mac address using the following code from the DC git however I can't get this to mesh up with the boxplot reducer.. Am I going in the right direction here?

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#accumulate-values

```
var allDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d; });

function accumulate_group(source_group) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            var cumulate = 0;
            return source_group.all().map(function(d) {
                cumulate += d.counter;
                return {key:d.mac, value:cumulate};
            });
        }
    };
}

var boxPlotDim = accumulate_group(allDim);

var boxPlotGroup = boxPlotDim.group().reduce(
    function(p,v) {
        p.push(v.value());
        return p;
    },
    function(p,v) {
        p.splice(p.indexOf(v.value()), 1);
        return p;
    },
    function() {
        return [];
    }
);

var boxPlot = dc.boxPlot("#boxPlot");
boxPlot
    .width(1200)
    .height(600)
    .dimension(vendor)
    .group(boxPlotGroup)
    .tickFormat(d3.format('.1f'))
    .elasticY(true)
    .elasticX(true)
;
```

Thanks Adam

Comment: Yeah, double groupings don't exist in crossfilter currently. You could create a [fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups) that reduces the data a different way. Or it's often possible to create a complex reduction that does it all in one pass. I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to do - I'm probably just tired - but just wanted to affirm that yes, groupings are not recursive.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gordon, I'll scratch double groupings off! I'll have a look now into fake groups and have a play around with reducers. I have a tendency to waffle.. I'm simply trying to get an array together for the box plot that that contains a total count of the networks single devices have connected to, that I can then group by the manufacturer / vendor.

Ex. Apple [7,5,10,2]  = four apple devices.. device one has connected to 7 networks... ect.. Then I'll continue this for the other manufactures in my data

Comment: Added some more code to my question. I've had a go at implementing this fake group to accumulate the amount of networks per device to then be passed to the box plot reducer but I'm having no luck still. https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#accumulate-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally we'd really like to use a simple dimension over vendors here, in case we want to filter using a brush on the boxplot.

So then the question becomes: how do we reduce twice, once to get counts per MAC address, and then again to turn those counts into an array.

The first part has a standard answer: just reduce to an object instead of a value:

```
var vendorMacCountsGroup = vendor.group().reduce(
  function(p, v) { // add
    p[v.mac] = (p[v.mac] || 0) + v.counter;
    return p;
  },
  function(p, v) { // remove
    p[v.mac] -= v.counter;
    return p;
  },
  function() { // init
    return {}; // macs;
  }
);
```

I recently described this pattern [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51165587/676195), so I won't go into the details here.

Here's the sample output: bins are vendors, and each value is an object mapping mac addresses to counts:

```
[
  {
    "key": "Asustek Computer Inc.",
    "value": {
      "1c:b7:2c:48": 8,
      "1c:b7:be:ef": 3
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "Huawei Technologies Co.Ltd",
    "value": {
      "dc:d9:16:3d": 14,
      "dc:da:16:3d": 2,
      "dc:d9:16:3a": 1,
      "dc:d9:16:3b": 1
    }
  },
  ...
```

Next, we really just want the counts and to forget the MAC addresses. JavaScript has a nice built-in function for this, [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values). We just need to apply to that to each of the object-values in our group. We'll also throw out any zeros, because that will only happen when a MAC address has been filtered out somewhere else.

```
function flatten_object_group(group) {
  return {
    all: function() {
      return group.all().map(function(kv) {
        return {
          key: kv.key,
          value: Object.values(kv.value).filter(function(v) { return v>0; })
        }; 
      });
    }
  };
}
var boxPlotGroup = flatten_object_group(vendorMacCountsGroup);
```

Sample output:

```
[
  {
    "key": "Asustek Computer Inc.",
    "value": [
      8,
      3
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Huawei Technologies Co.Ltd",
    "value": [
      14,
      2,
      1,
      1
    ]
  },
  ...
```

Your sample data only had one MAC address per vendor, so I added some bogus data, and got a decent-looking boxplot:

[image: it's a boxplot]

[Fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/cus0p7yL/31/).

#### Taking only the top ten by #MACs

As an example of how you might trim the data if there are too many boxes, here's how you would sort by number of MAC addresses, and take only the 10 "most popular" vendors:

```
function top_ten_by_length(group) {
  return {
    all: function() {
      return group.all().sort(function(a,b) {
        return b.value.length - a.value.length;
      }).slice(0, 10);
    }
  };
}
```

Compose them like this:

```
var boxPlotGroup = top_ten_by_length(flatten_object_group(vendorMacCountsGroup));
```

This is off the top of my head and untested so please edit/comment if there is some glitch.

Comment: One very last question.. I promise.. Is there a way to limit the amount of bars that plot on the box plot chart? I have 150+ vendors so unless I've made a selection elsewhere everything's on on top of itself. I've tried .cap(10) as I've done on rowcharts but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks Adam

Comment: That's weird about the CSS - maybe somehow you had CSS from an earlier version than the library you're using. Using the 3.x CSS with 2.x library should work fine.

Comment: It's true, .cap() is only available on some charts. You could wrap the fake group in another one. I'm not sure what criteria you want but I'll add a quick example above.

Comment: That works perfectly for limiting the bars plot to 10! Thanks you so much for the assistance Gordon, I can focus on data collection and writing my report now.. It was a learning curve but I feel like I'm much better prepared for when I next use dc!

Comment: Hey gordon I've got a question about the reducers you've showed me in this post, with regards to grouping data further and what you mean by a simple dimension (I'm guessing that's a data slice that you have defined in your data set?). I posted it here so I could format it a bit better. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51677899/dc-js-using-two-reducers-without-a-simple-dimension-and-second-grouping-stage

Comment: Added sample output to clarify data shapes and what is going on.