# dc.js Using two reducers without a simple dimension and second grouping stage

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

Quick question following up my response from this post: 
[dc.js Box plot reducer using two groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51639127/dc-js-box-plot-reducer-using-two-groups/51653980?noredirect=1#comment90277277_51653980)
Just trying to fully get my head around reducers and how to filter and collect data so I'll step through my understanding first.

Data Format:

```
{
    "SSID": "eduroam",
    "identifier": "Client",
    "latitude": 52.4505,
    "longitude": -1.9361,
    "mac": "dc:d9:16:##:##:##",
    "packet": "PR-REQ",
    "timestamp": "2018-07-10 12:25:26",
    "vendor": "Huawei Technologies Co.Ltd"
}
```

(1) Using the following should result in an output array of key value pairs  (Key MAC Address & Value Count of networks connected to):

```
var MacCountsGroup = mac.group().reduce(
    function (p, v) {
        p[v.mac] = (p[v.mac] || 0) + v.counter;
        return p;
    },
    function (p, v) {
        p[v.mac] -= v.counter;
        return p;
    },
    function () {
        return {}; // KV Pair of MAC -> Count
    }
);
```

(2) Then in order to use the object this must be passed flattened so it can be passed to a chart as follows:

```
function flatten_object_group(group) {
    return {
        all: function () {
            return group.all().map(function (kv) {
                return {
                    key: kv.key,
                    value: Object.values(kv.value).filter(function (v) {
                        return v > 0;
                    })
                };
            });
        }
    };
}

var connectionsGroup = flatten_object_group(MacCountsGroup);
```

(3) Then I pass mac as a piechart dimension & connectionsGroup as the group. This gives a chart back a chart with roughly 50,000 slices based on my dataset.

```
var packetPie = dc.pieChart("#packetPie");
packetPie
    .height(495)
    .width(350)
    .radius(180)
    .renderLabel(true)
    .transitionDuration(1000)
    .dimension(mac)
    .ordinalColors(['#07453E', '#145C54', '#36847B'])
    .group(connectionsGroup);
```

[image]

This works A'OK and I follow up to this point.

(4) Now I want to group by the values given out by the first reducer, i.e I want to combine all of the mac addresses with 1 network connection, 2 network connections and so on as slices.

How would this be done as a dimension of "Network connections"? How can I produce this summarized data which doesn't exist in my source data and is generated from mac?

Or would this require an intermediate function between the first reducer and flattening to combine all of the values from the first reducer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do all of that to get a pie chart of mac addresses.

There are a few faulty understandings in points 1-3, which I guess I'll address first. It looks like you copy and pasted code from the previous question, so I'm not really sure if this helps.

(1) If you have a dimension of mac addresses, reducing it like this won't have any further effect. The original idea was to dimension/group by *vendor* and then reduce counts for each *mac address*. This reduction will group by *mac address* and then further count instances of each mac address within each bin, so it's just an object with one key. It will produce a map of key value pairs like

```
{key: 'MAC-123', value: {'MAC-123': 12}}
```

(2) This will flatten the object within the values, dropping the keys and producing just an array of counts

```
{key: 'MAC-123', value: [12]}
```

(3) Since the pie chart is expecting simple key/value pairs with the value being a number, it is probably unhappy with getting values like the array `[12]`. The values are probably coerced to `NaN`.

(4) Okay, here's the real question, and it's actually not as easy as your previous question. We got off easy with the box plot because the "dimension" (in crossfilter terms, the keys you filter and group on) existed in your data.

Let's forget the false lead in points 1-3 above, and start from first principles.

There is no way to look at an individual row of your data and determine, without looking at anything else, if it belongs to the category "has 1 connection", "has 2 connections", etc. Assuming you want to be able to click on slices in the pie chart and filter all the data, we'll have to find another way to implement that.

But first let's look at how to produce a pie chart of "number of network connections". That's a little bit easier, but as far as I know, it does require a true "double reduce".

If we use the default reduction on the mac dimension, we'll get an array of key/value pairs, where the key is a mac address, and the value is the number of connections for that address:

```
[
  {
    "key": "1c:b7:2c:48",
    "value": 8
  },
  {
    "key": "1c:b7:be:ef",
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "key": "6c:17:79:03",
    "value": 2
  },
  ...
```

How do we now produce a key/value array where the key is number of connections, and the value is the array of mac addresses for that number of connections?

Sounds like a job for the lesser-known [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). This function is the likely inspiration for crossfilter's `group.reduce()`, but it's a bit simpler: it just walks through an array, combining each value with the result of the last. It's great for producing an object from an array:

```
var value_keys = macPacketGroup.all().reduce(function(p, kv) {
  if(!p[kv.value])
    p[kv.value] = [];
  p[kv.value].push(kv.key);
  return p;
}, {});
```

Great:

```
{
  "1": [
    "b8:1d:ab:d1",
    "dc:d9:16:3a",
    "dc:d9:16:3b"
  ],
  "2": [
    "6c:17:79:03",
    "6c:27:79:04",
    "b8:1d:aa:d1",
    "b8:1d:aa:d2",
    "dc:da:16:3d"
  ],
```

But we wanted an array of key/value pairs, not an object!

```
var key_count_value_macs = Object.keys(value_keys)
    .map(k => ({key: k, value: value_keys[k]}));
```

Great, that looks just like what a "real group" would produce:

```
[
  {
    "key": "1",
    "value": [
      "b8:1d:ab:d1",
      "dc:d9:16:3a",
      "dc:d9:16:3b"
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "2",
    "value": [
      "6c:17:79:03",
      "6c:27:79:04",
      "b8:1d:aa:d1",
      "b8:1d:aa:d2",
      "dc:da:16:3d"
    ]
  },
  ...
```

Wrapping all that in a "fake group", which when asked to produce `.all()`, queries the original group and does the above transformations:

```
function value_keys_group(group) {
  return {
    all: function() {
      var value_keys = group.all().reduce(function(p, kv) {
        if(!p[kv.value])
          p[kv.value] = [];
        p[kv.value].push(kv.key);
        return p;
      }, {});
      return Object.keys(value_keys)
        .map(k => ({key: k, value: value_keys[k]}));
    }
  }
}
```

Now we can plot the pie chart! The only fancy thing here is that the value accessor should look at the length of the array for each value (instead of assuming the value is just a number):

```
packetPie
    // ...
    .group(value_keys_group(macPacketGroup))
    .valueAccessor(kv => kv.value.length);
```

[image: packet pie]

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/mnvozp5u/24/).

However, clicking on slices won't work. I'll return to that in a minute - just want to hit "save" first!

#### Part 2: Filtering based on counts

As I remarked at the start, it's not possible to create a crossfilter dimension which will filter based on the count of connections. This is because crossfilter always needs to look at each row and determine, based only on the information in that row, whether it belongs in a group or filter.

If you add another chart at this point and try clicking on a slice, [everything in the other charts will disappear](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/hj4o1ub8/6/). This is because the keys are now counts, and counts are invalid mac addresses, so we're telling it to filter to a key which doesn't exist.

However, we can obviously filter by mac address, and we also know the mac addresses for each count! So this isn't so bad. It just requires a [filterHandler](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#filterHandler__anchor).

Although, hmmm, in producing the fake group, we seem to have forgotten `value_keys`. It's hidden away inside the function, and then let go.

It's a little ugly, but we can fix that:

```
function value_keys_group(group) {
  var saved_value_keys;
  return {
    all: function() {
      var value_keys = group.all().reduce(function(p, kv) {
        if(!p[kv.value])
          p[kv.value] = [];
        p[kv.value].push(kv.key);
        return p;
      }, {});
      saved_value_keys = value_keys;
      return Object.keys(value_keys)
        .map(k => ({key: k, value: value_keys[k]}));
    },
    value_keys: function() {
      return saved_value_keys;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, every time `.all()` is called (every time the pie chart is drawn), the fake group will stash away the `value_keys` object. Not a great practice (`.value_keys()` would return `undefined` if you called it before `.all()`), but safe based on the way dc.js works.

With that out of the way, the `filterHandler` for the pie chart is relatively simple:

```
packetPie.filterHandler(function(dimension, filters) {
  if(filters.length === 0)
    dimension.filter(null);
  else {
    var value_keys = packetPie.group().value_keys();
    var all_macs = filters.reduce(
      (p, v) => p.concat(value_keys[v]), []);
    dimension.filterFunction(k => all_macs.indexOf(k) !== -1);
  }
  return filters;
});
```

The interesting line here is another call to `Array.reduce`. This function is also useful for producing an array from another array, and here we use it just to concatenate all of the values (mac addresses) from all of the selected slices (connection counts).

Now we have a working filter. It doesn't make too much sense to combine it with the box plot from the last question, but [the new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/hj4o1ub8/14/) demonstrates that filtering based on number of connections does work.

#### Part 3: what about zeroes?

As commonly comes up, crossfilter considers a bin with value zero to still exist, so we need to ["remove the empty bins"](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#remove-empty-bins). However, in this case, we've added a non-standard method to the first fake group, in order to allow filtering. (We could have just used a global there, but globals are messy.)

So, we need to "pass through" the `value_keys` method:

```
function remove_empty_bins_pt(source_group) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                return d.key !== '0';
            });
        },
        value_keys: function() {
            return source_group.value_keys();
        }
    };
}
packetPie
  .group(remove_empty_bins_pt(value_keys_group(macPacketGroup)))
```

Another oddity here is we are filtering out the *key* zero, and that's a string here!

[Demo fiddle!](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/oagL45nc/2/)

Alternately, here's a better solution! Do the bin filtering before passing to `value_keys_group`, and then we can use the ordinary `remove_empty_bins`!

```
function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                //return Math.abs(d.value) > 0.00001; // if using floating-point numbers
                return d.value !== 0; // if integers only
            });
        }
    };
}
packetPie
    .group(value_keys_group(remove_empty_bins(macPacketGroup)))
```

[Yet another demo fiddle!!](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/oagL45nc/4/)

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer! This is an intense use of dc.js and it would be cool to see a demo when you get it all together. (My email address is easy to find.)

Comment: Looking back at my answer, I'm starting to see some patterns emerge - I have answered this question once or twice before. Wondering if a general purpose "double-reduce" utility could be written.

Comment: Thanks you so much for such a detailed explanation Gordon, stepping through the groupings and showing the JSON has really helped cleared things up for me! I've been having a play with this for the last hour or so and I have a Q about your solution. When making a selection on a different chart a segment 0 appears this is a bin containing the remainder of the selections? How could this be obscured? I've tried the following which works to get rid of the segment however it then stops the chart from being selectable by what seems like removing access to you value_keys fake group...

Comment: function remove_no_connections(source_group) {
        return {
            all: function () {
                return source_group.all().filter(function (d) {
                    return d.key != 0;
                });
            }
        };
    }


  // Then group for pie

  .group(remove_no_connections(value_keys_group(macPacketGroup)))

Comment: Good point. That looks fine, you'll just have to pass `value_keys` through `remove_no_connections`. `value_keys: function() { return source_group.value_keys(); }`

Comment: Making a selection on 1 network to macs (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYRle.png) 0 segment appears. After adding the function above.. basically remove empty bins but looks at key being 0 and I then filter by a manufacturer I get a correct chart showing the network counts without 0 but It's not selectable (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ3al.png)

Comment: I meant to add a `value_keys` method to your fake group that passes through to the other fake group. I can edit my answer when I get back to the computer, under a cat right now. :)

Comment: updated with one way and then a better way to remove zeroes!

Comment: This is great, please share the result and let's add that to the documentation