# Normalized(100%) Stacked Bar and Row Chart in Dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I could not find any example on how to go about to achieve this task. I found out there is an attempt to implement a stacked row chart in Dc.js but is not added to the master branch https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/397. Any pointers would be heplful?

Comment: Sorry, as discussed in the issue, stacked row charts are not supported. It seems to be too difficult to merge the stack mixin with the row chart. I think some folks have rotated the bar chart, but it's not exactly the same thing.

Comment: That's a shame, I've been trying to put together a collection of Dc.js Chart in angular. I'm adding a snippet of what I created https://imgur.com/gallery/4Nq6IVn . I'm wondering if i can use the Custom Chart (Row Stack) in DC.js. Also wondering if I could implement Normalized Stacked Column Chart.

Comment: I’m not sure what Custom Chart (Row Stack) you’re referring to. Yes, normalized stack is possible; I’ll answer that part. And yes it’s a shame that no one has managed to solve row stack in dc.js. Unfortunately the coordinate grid mixin assumes that keys are X and values are Y in a lot of places, so the row chart was implemented without it.

Comment: A quick search for [dc.js] normalized returns this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51141367/stacked-bar-chart-by-units-percentage/51165402#51165402